# BlazeDS JMS Adapter disconnection

Tags: apache-flex, jms, activemq-classic, jmx, blazeds

I Integrate Blazeds messaging system with  ActiveMQ: .

I configure BlazeDS to create a durable flex destination using the `flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.JMSAdapter` (the configuration is below).

I was able to create a small application that register to the topic and recieve the message. Since I need to recieve the message sent when I was offline I create a durable query.

Everything works fine as long as I unsubscribe correctly the flex consumer.

My problem is when the flex consumer do not call unsubscribe. For Example when I 
close the browser.

In this situation the topic is still Active (I can see it from the ActiveMQ web console) and it consume the messages.

When I connect again with a new instance of the flex application the connection is OK but I did not recieve any message. Nor the ones sent whne I was away, neither the new one.
I cannot even delete the topic using the ActiveMQ web console:`javax.jms.JMSException: Durable consumer is in use`.

The only solution is to delete the topic is restart the webapplication containg the BlazeDS broker.

Can someone give me another solution?

this is my blazeds configuration

```
  <adapters>
    <adapter-definition id="actionscript" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.ActionScriptAdapter" default="true" />
    <adapter-definition id="jms" class="flex.messaging.services.messaging.adapters.JMSAdapter"/>
</adapters>

...

  <destination id="warehouse-topic-jms">
    <properties>
        <jms>
            <destination-type>Topic</destination-type>
            <message-type>javax.jms.ObjectMessage</message-type>
            <connection-factory>java:comp/env/jms/flex/TopicConnectionFactory</connection-factory>
            <destination-jndi-name>java:comp/env/jms/warehouse</destination-jndi-name>
            <delivery-mode>PERSISTENT</delivery-mode>
            <message-priority>DEFAULT_PRIORITY</message-priority>
            <acknowledge-mode>AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE</acknowledge-mode>
            <initial-context-environment>
                <property>
                    <name>Context.INITIAL_CONTEXT_FACTORY</name>
                    <value>org.apache.activemq.jndi.ActiveMQInitialContextFactory</value>
                </property>
                <property>
                    <name>Context.PROVIDER_URL</name>
                    <value>tcp://localhost:61616</value>
                </property>
            </initial-context-environment>
        </jms>
        <server>
            <durable>true</durable>             
        </server>
    </properties>

    <adapter ref="jms"/>
</destination>
```

this is the Tomcat context to expose the JNDI resources

```
<Resource name="jms/flex/TopicConnectionFactory"
    type="org.apache.activemq.ActiveMQConnectionFactory"
    description="JMS Connection Factory"
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
    brokerURL="tcp://localhost:61616"
    brokerName="myBroker"/>
<Resource name="jms/warehouse"
    type="org.apache.activemq.command.ActiveMQTopic"
    description="warehouse.topic"
    factory="org.apache.activemq.jndi.JNDIReferenceFactory"
    physicalName="warehouse.topic"/>
```

and this is my flex consumer

```
<mx:Consumer id="consumer"   
                 channelConnect="consumer_channelConnectHandler(event)" 
                 channelFault="consumer_channelFaultHandler(event)" destination="warehouse-topic-jms"
                 fault="consumer_faultHandler(event)" message="consumer_messageHandler(event)"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

The only solution I found is to use the JMX MBEAN exposed by BlazeDS to force the JMSAdapter to remove the ActiveMQ Topic.
In this way I can recreate a new Topic with the same clientID and recieve the messages.

Here the code of the Java method I implemented

```
public boolean deleteTopicQueue(String clientId) throws Exception {
        if(clientId==null){
            throw new Exception("Error removing topic: null name provided");
        }
        clientId=clientId.trim();
        JMXServiceURL url = new JMXServiceURL(DEFAULT_JMX_ADAPTER_URL);
        try (JMXConnector jmxc = JMXConnectorFactory.connect(url, null)){
            MBeanServerConnection mbsc = jmxc.getMBeanServerConnection();
            ObjectName pattern = new ObjectName(DEFAULT_JMSADAPTER_MEAN_QUERY);
            Set<ObjectName>  names =
                new TreeSet<ObjectName>(mbsc.queryNames(pattern, null));

            if(names.size()<=0){
                logger.info("Error Removig topic "+clientId+": No JMSAdapter found ");
                throw new Exception("Error Removig topic "+clientId+": No JMSAdapter found ");
            }

            while(names.iterator().hasNext()){
                ObjectName ob =  names.iterator().next();
                JMSAdapterControlMBean obProxy =  JMX.newMXBeanProxy(mbsc, ob,JMSAdapterControlMBean.class);
                String[] consumerList=  obProxy.getTopicConsumerIds();
                for(String consumer :consumerList){
                    if(consumer.trim().equals(clientId)){
                        logger.info("Removing "+consumer+" from "+ob.getCanonicalName());
                        obProxy.removeConsumer(consumer);
                        return true;
                    }
                }
            }
            logger.debug("No consumer with ID "+clientId+" Found");
            return false;
        } catch (Exception e) {
            logger.info("Error Removig topic "+clientId+": No JMSAdapter found ");
            throw new Exception("Error Removig topic "+clientId+" :"+e.getMessage());
        }
    }
```